# Are FDS scheme and ROE-FDS scheme the same?

Tags: numerics, finite-volume

In SU2 documentation about the numerical schemes (https://su2code.github.io/docs_v7/Convective-Schemes/) FDS is mentioned as a "standalone" method.

Yet, when looking online for more information about FDS scheme, it seems it is just a preconditioning for the ROE scheme. And this seems coherent with the fact that has reported [here](https://economon.github.io/docs/AIAA-2018-3111.pdf) it is a necessary treatment for the poor convergence of compressible codes (the main cause is the artificial dissipation) for this type of simulations.

Hence my question: are FDS scheme and ROE-FDS scheme the same with FDS being only a treatment to make ROE scheme work well in incompressible cases?